# QString replace element

Tags: c++, qt5, qstring

I try to replace  `QString img=":/images/f0000.png";`

If pVaule is 51 img should be `":/images/f0001.png"`

If pVaule is 71 img should be `":/images/f0021.png"`

But my result is 
pVaule is 51 img

```
":/images/f000\u0001.png"
```

pVaule is 71 img

`":/images/f00\u0002\u0001.png"`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the ASCII value of numbers...

```
if(pValue>=50 && pValue<=89)
{
    QString img=":/images/f0000.png";
    if(pValue>=50 && pValue<=59)
    {
        img.data()[12]='0';
        img.data()[13]='0'+char(pValue-50);
    }
    else if(pValue>=60 && pValue<=89)
    {
        img.data()[12]='0'+char(pValue-50)/10;
        img.data()[13]='0'+char(pValue-50)%10;
    }
}
```

Also, a better solution to this would be:

```
img.replace(10, 4, QString(4 - QString::number(pValue - 50).length()), '0') + QString::number(pValue - 50));
```

Comment: I am little confuse with one one line need time to figure but thanks